# Modify a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of chars

```
left = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

and the function

```
typer :: [Char] -> Char -> [Char]
typer left c = left ++ [c]
```

Which seems to work if I type `typer left 'a'` into `ghci` it returns `"helloa"` but if I then try to read `left` it returns `"hello"`. Where does the `"a"` go? is there anyway to manipulate `left` using the function?

[example of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUBfT.png)

Comment: The value returned from a function is *not* the parameter you are passing to it.

Comment: welcome to haskell, where values are immutable

Comment: Why do you expect the function to modify `left`? Why not `c` for example?

Answer (score 3):

Haskell functions are [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which means they can't have side effects such as modifying variables.  Your `typer` function computes a result *based* on its arguments, but it doesn't (and can't) actually modify its arguments.

As an analogy, in mathematics, if *n* is 4 then sqrt(*n*) is 2, but *n* is still 4 even after you've computed its square root.

If you want to capture the result of your function call so you can use it later, assign it to another variable:

```
right = typer left 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope! Values in Haskell are immutable.

You have declared your `left` to be equal to `"hello"`, and it will *always* be equal to `"hello"`. You can hide that particular `left` value with some new token called `left` in a closer scope (such as having a function argument called `left`, which will make the globally defined `left` invisible in the function body). There is however no way to change your declared `left` value[1].

A *new* string is returned by `typer`, and you have to hold onto that value if you want to hold onto `"helloa"`.

[1] In GHCi, you can hide previous definitions by re-defining them. This quietly re-purposes the existing name to point to a new value. You cannot do this in a Haskell source file.

Comment: Regarding your last statement: you *can* redefine variables with consecutive `let` statements in a `do` block, which hide earlier definitions of the same name.  The GHCi REPL is similar to a big `do` block in that regard.

Comment: Right, those are implicitly nested scopes, and you can do the same by explicitly nesting `let .. in` and `where` blocks in pure code. It's probably more confusing for newcomers in the latest GHCi because the `let` keyword is no longer required there for bindings, and it looks like you're doing regular Haskell declaration in the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Not usually, no. Usually, Haskell variables are not mutable. There are however libraries that contain mutable variables. For example, `Data.IORef` contains `IORef`, which is mutable. I will explain how to use them below, but as a general rule, using I would recommend against it, and instead write your code in a more functional manner.

With IORef, your function `typer` can be rewritten

```
typer :: IORef [Char] -> Char -> IO()
typer left c = writeIORef left . (++[c]) =<< readIORef left
```

Let us consider its different parts.

- `readIORef left` pulls out the value `"hello"` from the `IORef` and wraps it in the `IO` monad.
- `f =<< x` takes `x`, which is wrapped in a monad, unwraps it and passes it as an argument to `f`, but **only** if we promise that `f` returns a value wrapped in the same monad. Here, `x` is `"hello"` wrapped in `IO` and `f` is `writeIORef left . (++[c])`.
- `.` combines the functions `writeIORef left` and `(++[c])` into one, so that `(++[c])` is applied before `writeIORef left`.
- `(++[c])` appends the character `c`.
- `writeIORef left` returns an empty action wrapped in `IO` (`IO()`), but it has the side effect that the value of the `IORef` `left` is modified. Since it returns a value wrapped in `IO`, the promise we made to `=<<` is fulfilled.

With the above function, the code

```
main :: IO()
main = do x <- newIORef "hello"
          typer x 'a'
          readIORef x >>= print
```

should yield the desired effect.